# Tangent Line to the Curve of Intersection of Two Surfaces

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, asymptote

The surfaces $f (x; y; z) = x^2 + y^2 - 2 = 0$ and $g(x; y; z) = x + z - 4 = 0$
meet in an ellipse E. How to plot it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of figures are simple using the 3d capabilities of Ti*k*Z, i.e. `3d` and `perspective` libraries. These capabilities are limited, but enough to draw these surfaces.

I made a style to draw inside the plane, shifting the origin, setting the canvas, rotating it and with an appropriate scale. There are other, more conventional, styles for the lines and fillings of each surface.

My figure is more realistic that your example but I took the liberty to change the point (1,1,3) for another one near it, because the `isometric view` is not very good with this point. If you need exactly the point (1,1,3) you can change my angle `\a` to 45, but you'll see what I said about the view. Another option is to change the view too, but it will require to change accordingly all the angles involved...

All said, this is what I propose:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc,perspective}

\tikzset
{
  at the plane/.style={shift={(0,0,4)},rotate around y=45,canvas is xy plane at z=0,xscale=\r},
  at the top/.style={canvas is xy plane at z=6},
  axis/.style={thick,-latex},
  vector/.style={thick,-stealth},
  cylinder back/.style={blue,left color=cyan,right color=blue!30,fill opacity=0.7},
  cylinder front/.style={blue,left color=blue,right color=cyan!30,fill opacity=0.5},
  plane/.style={thick,orange,fill=orange,fill opacity=0.2},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[isometric view,rotate around z=180,
                    line cap=round,line join=round]
  \pgfmathsetmacro\r{sqrt(2)}     % radius
  \pgfmathsetmacro\a{50}          % angle for P point
  \pgfmathsetmacro\xp{\r*cos(\a)} % x for P
  \pgfmathsetmacro\yp{\r*sin(\a)} % y for P
  \pgfmathsetmacro\zp{4-\xp}      % z for P
  % coordinates
  \coordinate  (O) at (0, 0,0); % origin
  \coordinate  (T) at (1,-1,3); % tangent point
  \coordinate  (P) at ({\r*cos(\a)},{\r*sin(\a)},{4-\r*cos(\a)}); % point P (changed for a better view)
  % axes
  \draw[axis]  (O) -- (5,0,0) node[left]  {$x$};
  \draw[axis]  (O) -- (0,4,0) node[right] {$y$};
  \draw[thick] (O) -- (0,0,4);
  % cylinder, below the plane
  \draw[cylinder back]  (T) {[at the plane] arc (315:135:\r)} -- (135:\r) arc (135:315:\r) -- cycle;
  \draw[cylinder front] (T) {[at the plane] arc (-45:135:\r)} -- (135:\r) arc (135:-45:\r) -- cycle;
  % plane
  \draw[plane] (4,-3,0) -- (4,3,0) -- (-2,3,6) -- (-2,-3,6) -- cycle;
  % cylinder (above the plane) and z-axis
  \draw[cylinder back]  (T) {[at the plane] arc (315:135:\r)} {[at the top] -- (135:\r) arc (135:315:\r)} -- cycle;
  \draw[axis] (0,0,4) -- (0,0,7.5) node[above] {$z$};
  \draw[cylinder front] (T) {[at the plane] arc (-45:135:\r)} {[at the top] -- (135:\r) arc (135:-45:\r)} -- cycle;
  % vectors
  \draw[vector,blue!50!black] (P) --++ (2*\xp,2*\yp,0)       coordinate (f)  node[right] {$\nabla f$};
  \draw[vector,red]           (P) --++ (1,0,1)               coordinate (g)  node[left]  {$\nabla g$};
  \draw[vector,magenta]       (P) --++ (2*\yp,-2*\xp,-2*\yp) coordinate (fg) node[left]  {$\nabla f\times\nabla g$};
  \fill (P) circle (0.4mm);
  % right angles
  \begin{scope}[shift={(P)}]
    \draw ($0.2*(f)$) -- ($0.2*(f)+0.3*(g)$)  -- ($0.3*(g)$);
    \draw ($0.2*(f)$) -- ($0.2*(f)+0.1*(fg)$) -- ($0.1*(fg)$);
    \draw ($0.3*(g)$) -- ($0.3*(g)+0.1*(fg)$) -- ($0.1*(fg)$);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent... Thanks a lot